# appending images

Tags: c#

I have a number of images that I would like to append to each other to make a larger file.
I am not sure of the best way to do this and I am looking for suggestions. The resulting image would be either printed, saved to a file or copied to the clipboard.

Comment: How do you mean append? How would they be appended? What would the resulting image look like?

Comment: What do you mean with "append"? Do you want to copy second image to the right of the first one? Do you mean creating a multi-page TIFF? Or what?

Comment: @Oded Maybe its to create something like [this](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=4)

Comment: @ConradFrix - Maybe. Maybe not. The OP hasn't really given enough information. Perhaps he want them side by side? Or next to each other? Or layered on top of each other? Or... Or... Or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save them as one tiff file have  look to this[Save images into a multi-page TIFF file or add images to an existing TIFF file](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/SaveMultipageTiff.aspx)